# Multi-level nested array pairing

Tags: php, arrays

Multi-level nested array pairing
I have two different arrays. One with topics and one with notes. Those notes should be matched with the topics. The 'lay-out' of those arrays will match together. For example:

```
$topics = [
    'Opening',
    'Aanwezigen',
    'Opmerkingen vorige notulen',
    'Ingezonden stukken' => [
        'Jaarverslag 2019',
        'Jaarcijfers 2019' => [
            'Jaarcijfers info',
        ],
     ],
    'Jaarrekening 2019' => [
        'Voorstel tot vaststelling van de jaarcijfers 2019 (stempunt)',
        'Vaststelling dividenduitkering (stempunt)',
        'Bespreking reserverings- en dividendbeleid',
    ],
    'Rondvraag',
    'Afsluiting',
];


$notes = [
    'Opening: notes',
    'Aanwezigen: notes',
    'Opmerkingen vorige notulen: notes',`
    'Ingezonden stukken: notes' => 
        'Jaarverslag 2019: notes',
        'Jaarcijfers 2019: notes' => [
            'Jaarcijfers info: notes',
    ],
    ],
    'Jaarrekening 2019: notes' => [
        'Voorstel tot vaststelling van de jaarcijfers 2019 (stempunt): notes',
    'Vaststelling didividenduitkering (stempunt): notes',
    'Bespreking reserverings- en didividendbeleid: notes',
    ],
    'Rondvraag: notes',
    'Afsluiting: notes'
];
```

The preferred output would be like this:

```
Opening
Opening: notes

Aanwezigen
Aanwezigen: notes

Opmerkingen vorige notulen
Opmerkingen vorige notulen: notes
```

So the indexes of both array should be paired with each other. Like `Opening` with `Opening: notes` and `Aanwezigen` with `Aanwezigen: notes`.

I already tried this:

```
$iterator = new MultipleIterator();
$iterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($topics));
$iterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($notes));
foreach($iterator as $topicMinute) {
    echo $topicMinute[0] . "<br/>"
    echo $topicMinute[1] . "<br /><br />";
}
```

This works for non-nested arrays but not for the ones I am currently using. It gives me this error:

> Array to string conversion.

Any ideas on how I might implement this the best way? So the idea is that the file I'm working in receives two arrays, with the same 'lay-out' and to pair these to loop through it in one `foreach`. Maybe I should use something else than an `ArrayIterator`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your preferred output doesn't say anything about what you want from the combination of the nested arrays, which makes any answer just a guess. Can you please add the entire preferred output for your sample arrays?

Comment: I want the indexes to be equal to each other. For example, the index Opening should be paired with Opening: notes. The indexes are on the same level already, I just want to loop through both arrays in one foreach. @Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to combine the array together you can use [`array-map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with function of `null` -> this will able you to loop over the array and have value for both array in 1 index.

```
$arr = array_map(null, $topics, $notes);
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/gER9f)

Now you can loop over it and echo what ever you need: (notice I used **`print_r()`** as your inner value can be arrays)

```
foreach($arr as $e) {
    echo print_r($e[0]) . "<br/>"; // 
    echo print_r($e[1]) . "<br/><br/>";
}
```